# Can someone pls help me translate LINQ Query Syntax to Method Syntax?

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I've been trying to figure out how to translate the following LINQ query syntax to method syntax, but I just don't get it:

```
from exa in _context.Exams
from stu in exa.Class.Students
where exa.Id == 1
select new StudentFullName
{
    Id = stu.Id,
    FullName = stu.Person.FirstName + " " + stu.Person.LastName
}
```

The property `ICollection<Student> Students` from the table `Classes` for the many-to-many relationship with `Students` is causing my confusion.

I tried this:

```
_context.Exams
.Where(exa => exa.Id == id)
.Select(exa => new StudentFullName
{
    Id = exa.Class.Students.Select(stu => stu.Id),
    FullNamee = exa.Class.Students.Select(stu => stu.Person.FirstName + " " + stu.Person.LastName)
}).ToList();
```

But I can't create the class `StudentFullName` because the query returns `IEnumerable<int>` instead of `int` for each property.

That's what I get: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fcxx.jpg

That's what I should get: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oy0hT.jpg

EDIT: Tweaked the solution from tymtam and it worked

```
_context.Exams
.Where(exa => exa.Id == id)
.SelectMany(exa => exa.Class.Students
  .Select(stu => new StudentFullNameViewModel
  {
      Id = stu.Id,
      FullName = stu.Person.FirstName + " " + stu.Person.LastName
  })
).ToList()
```

Comment: Are you sure there is no join between exams and students?

Comment: Install ReSharper `Alt+Enter` and `Convert LINQ to Method Chain`. I would not recommend to do that, readability and maintainability of the query will be worse.

Comment: You should indent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very suspicious that:

1. there is no join between students and exams
2. `exa` is not used in the result object

A 1-to-1 translation is I think this:

```
var students2 = exams
  .Where(exa => exa.Id == id)
  .SelectMany(exa => exa.Class.Students
    .Select(stu => new StudentFullName
    {
        Id = stu.Id,
        FullNamee = stu.Person.FirstName + " " + stu.Person.LastName
    }))
  .ToList();
```

Comment: `SelectMany(exa => exa.Class.Students`

Comment: I tweaked the SelectMany as Svyatoslav pointed out and added the class StudentFullName instead of creating an anonymous object. Thank you very much tymtam and @SvyatoslavDanyliv

Comment: apparently entity framework does the join automatically when following its many-to-many convention (``public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }`` in ``Class`` model and ``public virtual ICollection<Class> Classes { get; set; }`` in ``Student`` model).
I use ``_context.Exams`` to access only the students of the specific class